# Usage of Any or Every

Tags: word-usage, questions

Which one of these is more correct:

"The process of adaptation is different in any case"

"The process of adaptation is different in every case"

Comment: Both are valid.  They mean different things.

Comment: The first means "Anyway, the process of adaptation is different."

Comment: Probably, first one is inclined more towards the Possibility in ANY case... And second one strictly tells us, it is present in EVERY case.. But, "in any case" as Matt has pointed out, is common idiom, so it all depends on the context with which it is being said.

Comment: @Matt Samuel I'd say that a non-pragmatic usage is ungrammatical.

Comment: I mean "The process of adaptation is different in any case" can't be used in place of  "The process of adaptation is different in each case / every case" (different from that in every other case: the implied things that are differed from are not implied by 'any').

Answer (score 2):

'***In any case***' can mean, effectively, the same as '***in every case***'.  The only nuance is that 'any' suggests that 'it doesn't matter which case you choose', whereas 'every' suggests that 'all cases are the same'.

An ambiguity is possible with '***in any case***' because it also has  idiomatic usage meaning either '*whatever may be the circumstances / at all events*' or '*anyhow / at any rate*'. (OED)

It is not clear from the OP which usage of 'in any case' is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Zero Vendler's article have explained nicely regarding this..

[Article link](http://academiclogbook.blogspot.com/2012/11/vendler-each-and-every-any-and-all-1962.html)

**For *ANY* [Copied from the article]...**

With Take any one, it is up to you to do the determining; here it does not make sense to ask back, Which one? Thus while in the former case [Take one] I merely fail to determine, in the latter case [Take any one] I call upon you to determine, in other words, I grant you unrestricted liberty of individual choice. (p. 79–80)

**For *EVERY* ...**

It means each and every item